# NSPredicate Syntax

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nspredicate

Can someone spot my mistake?...

```
pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ICAO contains[cd] %1$@ OR IATA contains[cd] %1$@ OR AirportName contains[cd] %1$@ OR CityName contains[cd] %1$@", searchText];
```

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "ICAO contains[cd] %1$@ OR IATA contains[cd] %1$@ OR AirportName contains[cd] %1$@ OR CityName contains[cd] %1$@"'**

:(

Comment: If you made a regular `NSString` using `stringWithFormat:` with this exact format, does it work? (It should...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that the NSPredicate formats support the printf style number placeholders.

`pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ICAO contains[cd] %@ OR IATA contains[cd] %@ OR AirportName contains[cd] %@ OR CityName contains[cd] %@", searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText];`